# JQuery .data not populating data attribute of <div> element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the following on an Ajax success:

```
$('#FormContent').data('seq',data.seqMod);
```

However, it does not work.

When I do `alert(data.seqMod);` it returns the correct value fine and the alert message has my integer in it (5) in this case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: JQuery caches `.data()` values internally, it doesn't update the attribute.

Comment: thank you, so the HTML tag does not get updated, correct?

Comment: The DOM element attribute doesn't get updated, correct.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I just output the same data attribute using a getter and it is indeed working. I will see if .attr does instead. Cheers

Comment: You just have to be consistent. If you set with `.attr()`, read with `.attr()`. If you set with `.data()`, read with `.data()`.

Comment: The only relationship between `.data()` and the attribute is the first time you read the data, it will initialize from the attribute. After that, they're not connected.